# How do I reference another object of the same class in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, object, containers

I'd like to create a container class for objects based on a Ruby array. I'd like to manipulate more than one of these containers, like concatenating 2 together. If I try this:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :name
end

class Things
  def initialize
    @things = Array.new
  end

  def addone( a )
    @things.push( a )
  end

  def append( list )
    list.each { |i| addone( i ) }
  end
end

item1 = Thing.new
item2 = Thing.new
item3 = Thing.new
item4 = Thing.new

item1.name = "Marty"
item2.name = "Fred"
item3.name = "Janice"
item4.name = "John"

list1 = Things.new
list1.addone( item1 )
list1.addone( item2 )

list2 = Things.new
list2.addone( item3 )
list2.addone( item4 )

list3 = Things.new
list3 = list2.append( list1 )
```

I get the error:

> in `append': undefined method`each' for # (NoMethodError) from ./test.rb:40:in `'

I've tried different approaches, for example creating an each method as it seems to want, but no luck so far. Any suggestions? And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to add `Things` to `Things`, you have two abilities: either to implement iterator methods on `Things` or simply decorate wrapped `Array`:

```
def append(list)
  case list
  when Enumerable then list.each { |i| addone(i) }
  when Things then list.instance_variable_get(:@things).each { |e| addone(i) }
  else raise "Sorry, can’t add #{list}"
end
```

Comment: My lazy approach: `def append(*list)` and then later `list.flatten.each { ... }`

Comment: Unless you want to be able to store arrays of arrays :)

Comment: @tadman BTW, I would not interfere method signature: `def append(list)` and later: `[*list].flatten.each`.

Comment: The advantage of `*list` is you can call it `append(x,y)` or `append([x,y])` depending on what you have at hand.

Comment: @tadman Well, I see, I have read a book “Ruby for beginners” :) In my experience, one has to re-think the approach seven times before declaring methods accepting `:opt` params. It leads to hard-to-debug errors, misusages etc. But I agree, of course, that whether you understand what you are doing, `*args` has a greater power.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there should be a getter/setter methods:

```
attr_accessor :things
```

Then you should change your `addone` method:

```
def append(list)
   list.things.each { |i| addone( i ) } # iterate through array items, not Things instance object
   self # return appended list object instead of unchanged provided argument – list1
end
```

Output of `list3.things`:

```
=> [#<Context::Thing:0x00000001adea48 @name="Janice">,
    #<Context::Thing:0x00000001ade9f8 @name="John">,
    #<Context::Thing:0x00000001adea98 @name="Marty">,
    #<Context::Thing:0x00000001adea70 @name="Fred">]
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/vTC/6)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this approach:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

class Things
  def initialize(things = [])
    @things = things
  end

  def push(thing)
    @things.push(thing)
  end

  def append(other)
    @things << other.to_a
  end

  def +(other)
    Things.new(@things + other.to_a)
  end

  def to_a
    @things
  end
end

some_things = %w(Marty Fred Janice John).map { |name| Thing.new(name) }

things_1 = Things.new
some_things.first(2).each { |thing| things_1.push(thing) }

things_2 = Things.new
some_things.last(2).each { |thing| things_2.push(thing) }

things_1.append(things_2) # This actually appends to things_1 rather than creating a new object
new_things = things_1 + things_2 # Creates a new object

# => #<Things:0x007ff85a1aa770 @things=[
# #<Thing:0x007ff85a1aa928 @name="Marty">,
# #<Thing:0x007ff85a1aa900 @name="Fred">,
# #<Thing:0x007ff85a1aa8d8 @name="Janice">,
# #<Thing:0x007ff85a1aa8b0 @name="John">]>
```

**Notes:**

1. Modified the API a bit to simplify the code.
2. Added a new method `+` as its intuitive in this context.

Comment: So, call to instance method `append` buries an instance, raising new one instead? I bet users of this code do not expect this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Yes it was bad. Have updated to make it more intuitive.